# simple method to print star pyramid with minimal code in dart?

Tags: dart

What is the simplest method to print star pyramid with minimal code?
It shouldn't use more than one looping statement.
I've produced pyramids with nested loop but I need more leaner code.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you need only one loop, when two loops are doing the job just fine? Also, what did you try so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Im a trainer, I was lecturing about making code leaner, soo...

Comment: Well, if you are the trainer, shouldn't you *answer* this question? Personal opinion: less characters does not make code leaner. If two loops are easier to understand, it beats one loop that is harder to understand any day.

Comment: the code below seems prettier isn't it?  that's what I'm talking about.

Comment: Well, the question is, what is "prettier"? What is it good for? The compiler is a machine, it doesn't care. And the human, well, the human cares for how easy it is to understand. And I think your question here demonstrates clearly, that the one-loop solution is in fact *harder* to understand. So by making it "prettier", a subjective, non-functional judgement, you also made it harder to work with. Does not seem to be something to strive for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const int row = 5;
  for(int i = 0;i<row;i++){
    stdout.writeln(" "*(row-i)+"* "*i);
  }
```

Comment: This one worked

Comment: I'm guessing that the compiler will optimize this but you should use a constant for `row` instead of a variable if you don't intend to change its value. In my humble opinion the 5 as a literal with a comment as to what it does would be even better.

Answer (score -1):

```
var b = 8;
int a =1;
for(int i=b;i>0;i--){
print(' '*i + '* '*a);
a=a+1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**